# PHP mapping through exploded string inserts weird [] at the end

Tags: php, arrays, explode

**PHP Version 5.6**
**Windows Server 2012**

I am currently experiencing this weird behaviour:

```
$string = "asdf";
echo $string; // asdf
$myArray = explode(" ", $string);
var_dump($myArray) // "array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "asdf"}[]"
print_r($myArray) // "Array( [0] => asdf )[]"

$someQuery = "SELECT * FROM table ";

foreach($myArray as $idx => $keyword){
   $someQuery .= "WHERE someColumn LIKE '%$keyword%'";
}
echo $someQuery // SELECT * FROM table WHERE someColumn LIKE '%asdf%'[]   <-- ????
```

Why does the `[]` appear at the end? And how do I get rid of it?

I thought that it might represent that I am var_dumping an array, but even when I map through it with foreach to create a dynamic query, these weird bracers get added at the end of the query, which destroy it.

If you need further information let me know.

Whole, unfiltered code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/PqvNtHDN

Comment: It works fine on my system

Comment: Updated my question with the connected string - notice how the bracers get added outside of the ''

Comment: It 's find on my server.array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "asdf"
}
SELECT * FROM table WHERE someColumn LIKE '%asdf%'

Comment: It's a fine working code. I'm not sure why you get output like that with `var_dump`.

Comment: Besides, I don't think this can produce a correct query.

Comment: Whether or not it can produce a correct query, the main question is whats up with these bracers...

Comment: can you post print_r($myArray) instead of var_dump in your question ?

Comment: This is totally correct code: https://3v4l.org/tAKBK. You definitely __not__ showing something to us.

Comment: @rahul_m updated my Question with the print_R

Comment: Maybe it is just a bug of win-version php or some unknown php-extension adds `[]` to output. But anyway - did you try to run this query? Does it work?

Comment: The query itself without the [] does run

Comment: @u_mulder I am not using any extensions. The function currently has no other functionality than what I posted here :/

Comment: Seems to be a bugg with my PHP Version and Windows Server.. I founda workaround. I have to presave the query string on a separate variable. Then manipulate the original query string and use the presaved string for the query.